# "used word" or "word used"?

Tags: grammaticality, word-order, syntactic-analysis

> The word used in that context should be gusto.
>   The used word is wrong.

Is it correct to place *used* after *word*? When should I use *word used*, and when *used word*?

Comment: "The used word is wrong" doesn't sound quite right; perhaps because of the ambiguity between the meanings 'the word that was used' and 'the word worn out from over-use'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first example, *the word used* is short for *the word that was used,* so *used* is a verb. In the second example, *used* is an adjective modifying *word.* In practice, there is very little difference between these, but you must use *word used* if you're going to qualify it with a reason or location.

For example:

> The *word used* is wrong.

Is correct, but:

> The *used word* in that context should be 'gusto'.

Is awkward, because you want to qualify *used* with *in that context,* so they should be together. The slightly changed meaning is more apparent with commas:

> The used word, in that context, should be 'gusto'.

Which is understandable, but again, is rather awkward and would benefit from re-wording.

Comment: Is then _the used word is wrong_ correct, or even acceptable?

Comment: +1 - However, `the used word` is not *wrong* - it is acceptable, if perhaps inadvisable for the contextual reasons you mention.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: *The used word is wrong* is correct.

Comment: @CJM: You're right. Edited a bit.